# Xquery with multiple elements

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql

I have a XML named 'fruits.XML' as follows

```xml
<fruits>
    <fruitbasket>
        <id>123 </id>
        <apple>Apple 1 </apple>
        <apple>Apple 2 </apple>
    </fruitbasket>
    <fruitbasket>
        <id> 1 </id>
        <apple>Apple 2 </apple>
        <apple>Apple 3 </apple>
    </fruitbasket>
</fruits>
```

How to find the baskets with Apple 2 in Xquery? I get a multiple element error when i use the matches in the Query.

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: Please post what you tried and the _exact error message_  you're receiving by copy-pasting it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 for $element in doc('fruits.xml')//fruitbasket
where $element/apple = 'Apple 2 '
return $element
```